# Azure site to site proposals with Strongswan IPSec

Tags: vpn, azure, ipsec, strongswan

Noob here trying to finish a project, I think I have it bar these damn proposals, this is for an Linux Ubuntu VPC Machine to Azure Cloud network interface, only thing I can't suss out is how to config my IKE and ESP at my end to match the Below -

IKEv2 Encryption | GCMAES256, AES256
IKEv2 Integrity | GCMAES256, SHA384, SHA256, SHA1
DH Group | DHGroup2
IPsec Encryption | GCMAES256, AES256
IPsec Integrity | GCMAES256, SHA256
PFS Group | None, PFS24, ECP384, ECP256, PFS2048, PFS2, PFS1

Every vairation I've tried so far

```
#ike=chacha20poly1305-sha512-curve25519-prfsha512,aes256gcm16-sha384-prfsha384-ecp384,aes256-sha1-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024! 
#ike=3des-sha1-modp1024! 
ike=aes256-sha256-modp1024,aes256-sha1-modp1024! 
#esp=chacha20poly1305-sha512,aes256gcm16-ecp384,aes256-sha256,aes256-sha1,3des-sha1! 
#esp=aes256-sha256-modp1024! 
esp=aes256-sha256-modp1024!
```

I've tried to follow and decipher things from -> https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/config/IKEv2CipherSuites.html but I can't figure out which ones to use

Comment: https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ConfigurationExamples this might be helpful